# Does actioncable support resuming from an offline client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have a javascript SPA application that needs to support a user being offline for brief periods of time.  I'm considering using actioncable for broadcasting changes the client may not be aware of.

If a websocket connection is lost for a brief amount of time, and then reconnected:  will the client receive messages which were broadcast while they were offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/action_cable_overview.html#broadcasting):

> Broadcastings are purely an online queue and time dependent. If a consumer is not streaming (subscribed to a given channel), they'll not get the broadcast should they connect later.

So no, the client will not receive messages sent when they were offline.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Action cable will trigger a reconnect when the client gains access to the Internet.

You can test this your self by logging connections on your server and your client, then taking the client offline and reconnecting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where will be messages be cached? I need to setup `redis` for that? is there any link or tutorial for the same?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran did you find any solution?